# Alternation with EOF producing odd output

Tags: antlr, antlr4

The following works fine:

```
testRoot
    : sqlStatement EOF ?
    ;
```

However, if I add in the following:

```
testRoot
    : sqlStatement (SEMI | EOF) ?
    ;
```

The same input now gives me the following error message:

> `line 1:8 extraneous input '<EOF>' expecting {<EOF>, SEMI}`

Is there something that I'm missing here, or why is that error popping up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EOF` really isn't something that's optional.  A token stream will always have an `EOF` token at the end of the stream.

```
testRoot: sqlStatement SEMI? EOF;
```

You always want an EOF at the end of a start rule.  Without it, ANTLR may be able to recognize a portion of your input, and will discard the remainder without an error.  With it, the rule says... this rule has to end with the `EOF` token, so it will consume all of the input to get to the `EOF` and will report any syntax errors it encounters.